# No breakpoints after gui figure copying?

Tags: matlab, debugging, user-interface

Say, I have two following files:

- A.m with matlab code that contains function callbacks and
- A.fig with corresponding user interface file.

Now, I'm making copy of these two files:

- A_copy.m
- A_copy.fig

These two files were created by just copying the first ones. Now the questions is, why debugger does not stop inside callbacks? Inside other function debugger stops in its normal way, but not in callbacks. Of course, I've changed function name in A_copy.m from A to A_copy.

Which problem may I face?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my God.

To fix this problem I had to go to main window editor properties and change NAME property. Just a string that contains title of the gui window. Why? Why? Why, Mathworks, WHY?

I can't believe it is made in so stupid way!